# How can I install apps/modules in odoo v9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have started using **odoo** and I would like to install some **modules** like **[Custom Invoice template](https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/master/report_custom_invoice/)**, Pls recommend some docs or steps to install new modules.

Answer (score 3):

1. Activate the developer mode by doing to About page (by clicking the user profile picture).
2. Go to settings choose "Users" from the menu Click the current user, and edit it by checking "Technical features"
3. Refresh the page
4. Unpacked the module at ../server/openerp/addons
5. Go to modules under settings and Click the "Update module list" menu item.
6. The app should display under local modules, so find your new module in Settings > Modules > Local Modules and click on the install button.

Answer (score 3):

I am just posting the best steps:

create a separate folder **custom_addons**   and place it inside the located folder of odoo  in parallel   with  addons folder like

**/opt/odoo/custom_addons** ,

Now your odoo directory have **two module source**  /opt/odoo/**addons** and /opt/odoo/**custom_addons**.

It's time to include this newly create folder in the addons path of odoo server .

Open your odoo server config :nano /etc/odoo-server.conf

append  the newly create addons in addons_path like:

```
addons_path = /opt/odoo/custom_addons,/opt/odoo/addons
```

save the file and restart your odoo server .

> Now **place** your new modules [create/purchased] in side the
>   **custom_addons** then  **update** module list and **search** the name of module and **install** it.